# How to avoid jQuery autocomplete dropdown being hidden by underlying flash object?

Tags: jquery, flash, z-index, jquery-autocomplete

I'm using `jQuery Autocomplete` just as in this example:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/remote-jsonp.html

The problem is, the area where you see the `Result` box in that example - that's where my flash object is.

So, when the autocomplete dropdown appears, *`most of the text is concealed by the flash object (which I can't move)`*.

**How can I make the autocomplete text appear over the flash object (concealing its view rather than vice versa)?**

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the wmode to transparent on your flash.

Answer (score 1):

"A Flash movie ... may display above all the layers, regardless of the stacking order ("z-index") of those layers."

"...**Using a WMODE value of 'opaque' or 'transparent'** will prevent a Flash movie from playing in the topmost layer and allow you to adjust the layering of the movie within other layers of the HTML document."

In other words, if your flash object is like `<object attr=value and so on>`, you need to add a `wmode` attribute: `<object wmode=transparent attr=value and so on>`.

http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/155/tn_15523.html

Answer (score 1):

The z-index not work until you set the wmode to transparent.

Answer (score 0):

You might also try giving your Result box a crazy z-index value. This approach has worked for me in the past. Simpy put, the z-index property specifies the stack order of an element.

Example CSS:

```
#resultbox {
   z-index:20000
}
```

Comment: unfortunately, if the wmode attribute of the flash object isn't set, the z-index will be ignored regardless of "crazy" value.